# How do I install ImageMagick with lcms support on a Mac?

Tags: mac-osx, imagemagick

I installed ImageMagick via MacPorts, but unfortunately it was installed with "--without-lcms" and "--with-lcms=no" even though it lists lcms as a dependency on the website: http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=imagemagick There is also no lcms variant to turn this on, that I can see. Lcms can be found here, by the way: http://www.littlecms.com/

Aside from MacPorts, I'm not aware of any other easy way to install ImageMagick.

Also, as background information, from what I've read on the internet, lcms is the best way to use ImageMagick to convert images between color profiles, say from CYMK to RGB in order to make them web-compatible (well, IE compatible). I've tried using ImageMagick without lcms to convert between color profiles using -colorspace and -profile options without success.

Anyway, any help on either installing ImageMagick with lcms support or alternative methods of converting image color profiles would be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The latest version if the ImageMagick port appears to include lcms, so it surprises me that it would build without it.

First off, make sure your portfiles are up to date.  Run `sudo port selfupdate` and then `sudo port upgrade ImageMagick`.  It's possible you have an old version of the portfile where it wasn't enabled.

If that doesn't work, run `sudo port uninstall ImageMagick` then `sudo port -d configure ImageMagick` and watch for a hint in the log about why it's being excluded.

If it looks like something in the portfile is responsible for it not building, you can modify it before it runs to change the options it uses.  running `port file ImageMagick` will show you the path of the portfile.  If you edit that file then run `sudo port install ImageMagick` it will use the portfile with your changes.  Beware, when you run `sudo port selfupdate` again, it will overwrite your changes.

If, after all that, it still doesn't work, I'd probably want to look at the output of `sudo port -d install ImageMagick` and see if anything looks out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sips does help you? It comes with MacOS (see man sips).

Two other options: (a) Use [fink](http://fink.sf.net) instead of MacPorts. (b) Build it yourself, without MacPorts. If you met all dependencies for building it, this shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I you use a version of ImageMagick upto 6.5.9-0 with MacPorts, it disables lcms by default, but it has a lcms variant.

You can check this by looking at the [6.5.9-0 Portfile](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/ImageMagick/Portfile?rev=62884) :

```
variant lcms description {Support the Little Color Management System} {
        depends_lib-append \
            port:lcms
        configure.args-delete \
            --without-lcms
        configure.args-append \
            --with-lcms
    }
```

You can see that from [6.5.9-3](http://trac.macports.org/changeset/63755/trunk/dports/graphics/ImageMagick/Portfile), lcms support has been added :

```
ImageMagick:
    - update to 6.5.9-3
    - remove lcms variant; now always turn on Little Color Management System support (requested by nox)
    - simplify how -arch flags are removed from *-config scripts and do so always, not just when building universal
```

So the best way to do this is the update MacPorts and its portfiles :

```
sudo port -d selfupdate
sudo port -R upgrade ImageMagick
```